# Безопасное от малвари ведение логов на зараженной машине

Tags: логирование, виртуальная-машина, malware

На ВМ (`VirtualBox`) установлена `Windows 8.1`. На этой машине изучаю поведение малвари, которая шифрует файлы.

Действия:

1 > Запускаю файловый монитор (потом по логам хотел бы отследить изменения)

2 > Запускаю малварь

Через время компьютер перезагружается, и лог, который вел файловый монитор, тоже оказывается зашифрован.

**Вопрос:** каким образом можно "защитить" лог от изменений?

В хранилище за пределами ВМ его не хотелось бы писать, потому что это может и не помочь - если файловый монитор видит этот накопитель, увидит его и малварь.

Comment: А если малварь запускать под пользователем с ограниченными правами, а монитор под администратором, и у файла, соответственно, будут права только для администратора?..

Comment: @spopovru, малварь появляется на машине следующим образом: есть js скрипт, который тянет с удаленного сервера _некоторый_ файл, потом этот файл исполняется. Как таковой, бинарник я не запускаю. Если это важно, то уточню: тянет он какой-то файл, например, с расширением .jpeg, внешне вполне безобидый, но за этой _картинкой_ лежит сама малварь, как-то так упаковывают. Возможен ли Ваш способ в связи с вышесказанным ?

Comment: думаю, да. К сожалению, проверить нет возможности. Вижу всё как-то так: в VM создаёте пользователя-админа и пользователя с ограниченными правами. Идёте под админа, создаёте файл лога, ставите ему доступ только для админа, запускаете монитор. Идёте под обычного юзера, ловите малварь. В идеале, файл должен остаться цел... Проще всего создать снэпшот VM и проверить, т.к. мой ответ скорее теоретический, и результат зависит, в частности, от конкретной малвари.

Comment: @spopovru, спасибо за помощь, попробую. Что касается снэпшотов: есть ли какие-то тулзы, которые сравнивают снэпшоты, и показывают изменения в файловой системе, настройках или что-то вроде того ?

Comment: @isnullxbh: а файловый монитор который вы используете умеет отсылать отчёты по почте или инному интернет протоколу?

Comment: @МАН69К, нет, но это мысль ))) Спасибо Вам за идею.
UPD: извините, поторопился. Не мысль ) А когда он мне его должен будет отправить ? Отправит рано - возможно, что-то будет упущено, а позже уже нечего и отправлять будет.

Comment: Слать логи в сеть на хост по UDP прямо построчно по мере возникновения? Обратного доступа это не даёт.

Comment: @D-side, все, понял, спасибо. В т.ч. MAH69K